# How to show UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera in Landscape instead of Portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on iPad App, There when we click the right bar button i am giving an action like below:

```
    -(IBAction)camerabuttonAction:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;

    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
   [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50, -250, 500, 300) inView:appDelegate.splitview.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

My problem is, When i am in Land scape mode if i click the button. The camera show in portrait mode(Image appears in reverse mode to see). But, if i shake the iPad then it shows in LandScape.

For Orientation in ios6 i am using below method, But i did not write anything related to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

```
    - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||[self interfaceOrientation] ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
}
    else if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
}

}

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this. Extract from Apple Documentation:

> **Important**: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

It's here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: But, if i rotate my ipad portrait to landscape then the camera shows in LandScape  @Vincent Saluzzo

Comment: @Babul Yes, but this is Apple. You must use `AVFoundation.framework` to do this if you want to be proper and respect the recommandation of Apple.